# How to read header line of XML file

Tags: c#, xml

Need to write C# how to read configuration's version value = 1.0.1.2 in xml? I want to get this value then assign it to a string variable. Your example code would be much apprecaited. Thanks!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <Configuration version="1.0.1.2" createDate="2013-07-04T10:00:00">
    <config>
  .
  .
  .
  .
  </config>
  </Configuration>
```

Comment: Try something for yourself first, then come back when you have a specific problem including a sample of the code you have tried. [Here is a starting point](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307548)

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ to XML (this will load whole xml file into memory):

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(path_to_xml);
var version = (string)xdoc.Root.Attribute("version");
```

Or use XmlReader to avoid loading file into memory:

```
using(XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(path_to_xml))
{
    reader.MoveToContent();
    var version = reader.GetAttribute("version")
}
```